# Required number of iterations for multiple imputation of missing data

Tags: r, missing-data, survey, r-mice, likert

How can I decide the required number of iterations for convergence and the number of imputations for multiple imputation with `mice`?

I have longitudinal data with 8 likert items (ordinal variable) which I want to impute using the `polr` method in `mice`. All the 8 items have significant amount of missingness. How should I proceed with the multiple imputation?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Usually the default parameter for the number of imputations,  m=5 is just fine.